# Throwing Error on Log Out : - HTTP 403

Tags: asp.net, http, iis-7

I have a website that uses Forms Authentication.
When I test it in debug or in our dev server, in IIS7, it works fine.
When I publish it in Production, when I press the Logout button it gives an HTTP 403 Error.

The code I have for my logout button is:

```
     FormsAuthentication.SignOut()
     FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage()
```

Comment: I had the same situation recently where we saw 403 errors in production but not in dev or test.  The resolution for us was to add `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute for the Login (which corresponded to REDIRECT url for forms auth).  Still do not know why it was not failing in dev or test.

Comment: @DavidTansey where did you configure Allow Anonymous? On the Page itself or IIS?

Comment: Apologies...`[AllowAnonymous]` is a controller action attribute in ASP.NET MVC.  In WebForms the same idea is accomplished in the `WEB.CONFIG` -- see this for examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10367850/is-it-possible-to-allow-anonymous-user-to-browse-only-few-files-from-a-folder

Comment: @DavidTansey that didn't work out. I still can't access when logging out. But it's strange because if I am in my default page it logs out ok, when I enter other pages it gives the error

Comment: What URL is the FORMS AUTH redirect set to?  Is it the same as your 'default page'?

Comment: @DavidTansey yes. It points out to Login.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by changing

```
FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage()
```

to

```
Response.Redirect("./mypage.aspx")
~
```

At least, it worked for me