# Is there any way to create dynamic folder authorization setting in web.config asp.net c#

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have to create a folder at user creation time and also have to restrict other users from accessing that folder, so only that particular user can access that folder.

So finally I decided to allow and deny access to that folder using web.config. I don't want to do manual setting for every user. So how can I create dynamic folder authorization setting in web.config.

```
<location path="secure/files/support@userid.com">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="support@userid.com"/>
    <deny users="*"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
</location>
```

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: I think rather than using web.config file you should create a httphandler and access the folder thought that only. Because I thing there should a common place from where all these file should be access only then you will able to do this.

Comment: see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9990760/web-config-allow-location-access-for-specific-user