# use root web.config instead of sub-folders web.config

Tags: asp.net, webforms, web-config

i was trying to find out how can i use only root web.config instead of each one in any sub-folders of a ASP.NET Webforms project on the internet, but unfortunately i could not find propper answer. for example we have a project that has sub-folders like `Administrator` or `Users` and in the each one we have Web.Config files that authenticate users and restrict users by their permission.
With this mentioned issue, is it possible that we use **ONLY** a root web.config to authenticate users without any web.config in sub-folders?

Please help me.

Shadman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[You cannot combine `<location>` and `<authorization>` tags in a web.config file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/320259/1195620). You need to have config files for your sub-directories as well, or there is a workaround for a single config file that adds code to your aspx and code-behind files.

[Web.config allow location access for specific user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10404411/1195620)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `location` element 
example

```
<location path="subdir1">
        <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users ="*" />
        </authorization>
        </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: Thank you eminach, I know that we can use `location` tag in web.config in order to make permision for users, but it can be used on the web.config files that exist in sub-folders! When i put this tag on root web.config i got error from IIS.

Comment: Put non exist yet folders into major-floder and give permissions to all child folders

Comment: I didn't understand eminach, could you explain it please? or give me a help or reference about this? Thanks.